# How do I get/print a particular Q/A in printer-friendly format?

Tags: support

I found some Q/A very useful and want to print out it. For example [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/277) Q/A provides very useful information regarding scriptural resources. Though I can do that by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> but it looks like printing of web-page. So, is there any way to get/print printer-friendly version of a Q/A?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/):

- Set Hinduism from (drop-down) site list
- Insert/type Question ID; for example `15424` in case of the Q/A mentioned in question. (You can get ID from address bar `/questions/15424/` or by using `share` button)

Example screen-shot:

> [image: screen-shot]

- And you can get printer-friendly view by clicking on <kbd>Print</kbd> button.

---

For more information see related [announcement](https://stackapps.com/q/179) and MSE [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877/260388).